# unable to remove comma with "replace" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using toLocaleString, even though it outputs a value with a $ and comma delimited thousands values it likes a pure number in there without commas or $. I am trying to strip those out from the value before I put it in and it seems to work for the '$' but not the ','.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
$("#bob").blur(function() {
  NumberStripped = ($("#bob").val()).replace(',', '');
  NumberStripped = ($("#bob").val()).replace('$', '');
  console.log(NumberStripped);
  CurrencyValue = Number(NumberStripped).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  $('#bob').val(CurrencyValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="CurrencyTest" id="bob" maxlength="15">
```

To duplicate it you can basically type in 123456, click off, then click on and click off.

Some other posts suggested I use this to replace a comma:

```
NumberStripped = ($("#bob").val()).replace(/,/g, '');
```

I am not sure what that does but it still doesn't work.

To duplicate it you can basically type in 123456, click off, then click on and click off.

Comment: Your code in the jsfiddle is overwriting NumberStripped in the second call to String.replace

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I noticed you used parseFloat instead of number, like I had, how was that better? Did number not allow periods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you're only using the result of the second `replace()` call - you don't use the value created after you make the first replacement to remove the `,` characters.

That being said you can improve the logic by making a single `replace()` call which finds any character that isn't a digit or `.` and removes it. Then the formatting function will work fine. Try this:

```js
$("#bob").blur(function() {
  var numberStripped = $("#bob").val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
  var currencyValue = parseFloat(numberStripped).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  $('#bob').val(currencyValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="CurrencyTest" id="bob" maxlength="15">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided, I have it working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ntbvq05/42/

```
NumberStripped = ($("#bob").val()).replace(/,/g, '');
```

Your `NumberStripped` variable is being overwritten by the part that replaces the dollar sign right after the comma. Be careful of that.

--- edit >> jsFiddle that also handles dollar: https://jsfiddle.net/3ntbvq05/43/

Comment: Note that this produces `NaN` if you enter a value, blur then focus again as you haven't removed the `$` value.

Comment: Yes, sorry, was only answering the literal question. I've edited to show an updated jsFiddle that takes care of the dollar sign after

Comment: Yes, the edit worked great, I will use the answer that Rory since its one line had but I upvoted you too (even though my rank is too low to show). Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that is to use `.split(',').join('')`. Here is an example:

```js
$("#bob").blur(function() {
    var replaced;
    replaced = ($("#bob").val()).split(',').join('').split('$').join('');
    console.log(replaced);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="CurrencyTest" id="bob" maxlength="15">
```

Comment: @DanielBeck, nothings strange: `.split(',')` will split the string to array items using `,` as a separator, and then we are joining them together in one string via `.join('')` (`''` means that we joining them without a separator).

Comment: yup, I get it, I see how it works -- it's just an unusual way of accomplishing  a `.replace()`, I've never seen it done that way before.

Comment: @DanielBeck, yes, it's a little strange way, but for some reason I like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove multiple different characters is this:

```
.replace(/[,$]/g,'')
```

The square brackets mean "match any of these characters," in this case `,` and `$`.  The `g` makes it a global replace -- without that only the first matched instance will be removed.

```js
$("#bob").blur(function() {
    var replaced = Number(
      $("#bob")
         .val()
         .replace(/[,$]/g,'')
      ).toLocaleString('en-US', {
         style: 'currency',
         currency: 'USD',
         minimumFractionDigits: 2,
         maximumFractionDigits: 2
      }
    )
    $('#bob').val(replaced);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="CurrencyTest" id="bob" maxlength="15">
```